# 4DLCD display doesn't work with ESP32 via SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, esp32, tft

I have ESP32 custom made board and I cannot make it work with 4DLCD-35480320 (no touch) display via SPI. I triple checked all the wiring. Everything works except the display.

I used Arduino IDE and available libraries specifically for SPI and HX8357D, but no luck. I think I'm missing something but I connected everything as per datasheet. Any suggestions? It is the first time when I'm working with SPI displays, so not 100% sure if all the connections are correct.

[image: ESP32 Schematic]

[image: Display Schematic:]

[Display datasheet](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/451/4DLCD-35480320-Spec-V1.0-update_20180710-1608298.pdf)

Comment: Does the display work with a “generic” ESP32 board (i.e. to confirm your software is working correctly)? Are you able to monitor SPI signals with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope? Could you include a link to a datasheet for the 4DLCD display?

Comment: The connections look ok, as StarCat suggests, checking the signals are right is the next step.

Comment: I'll try to connect it to a dev board and see if this makes any difference. Software is just an example sketch from adafruit HX8357D library and I also tried TFT-eSPI library. All pins assigned as per hardware. Unfortunately, I dont have a oscilloscope, but sketch from adafruit prints in a serial terminal that lines have been drawn and all other shapes etc. So the code is working well and it turns backlight on normally. I attached display datasheet as well.

Comment: a MCU can't really tell if it's working or not. i 2nd the idea of trying to get just the LCD and an MCU working with a minimal setup.

Comment: Yesterday I tried it with a dev board and had no success. (Had to CNC a new PCB for 40p connector). The backlight works but nothing appears on the display. I'm gonna try to communicate with it without libraries. I'll need to learn how to do this first though. And if this won't help I think I'll need to acquire a logic analyzer. Thank you all for the suggestions! I appreciate that.

Comment: This is solved. They updated their datasheet and it is rev 1.2 on 4DLCD webpage, but still 1.0 on mouser. And in 1.2 they changed HX8357D for non touch displays to ILI9488, and swapped 8 and 11 pins.